# Change screen settings? (Confusing gnome color management settings on Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: 14.04, monitor, colors, gnome-color-manager

My screen on my Sony Vaio svt141190x is displaying very washed out colours and I meant to adjust them. I have been told I could do this via the gnome color manager that I can access via the settings menu.

Right now, this is what I'm seeing:

Sony SVT141190X - Uncalibrated
 - HP E201 - Not specified
 - DEL 1908FPBL - Not specified
 - SyncMaster - Not specified
 - D50 - Not specified
 - SVT141190X - Not specified

I can select the D50, which results in a reddish screen, the other options do not change anything. The tool tip over the root item reads "This device does not have a profile suitable for whole-screen color correction"

My options are: "add profile" "remove profile", and "view details". The option "Calibrate" is greyed out and not accessible.

I have tried googling for ICC profiles to add for my screen, but no luck.

I am not actually looking to do any fancy calibrations, I'd just like to deepen the blacks on my screen a bit, and add some contrast.

If it helps, I do have f.lux installed, and the brightness option is not working on my laptop. I do have to change the brightness by putting

```
echo 1200 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness > /dev/null
```

into the command line.

My graphics card is the on-board Intel Ivybridge mobile.